# Retrieving "invalid" value from a NumericUpDown Validating event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

When the user enters a value above `numericUpDown.Maximum`, the control's value is automatically set to the maximum. I'd like to display a MessageBox when this occurs, but I'm not able to do that because `control.Value` and `control.Text` already contain the automatically set value, maximum, when `Validating` event is raised.

```
private void numericUpDown_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
       NumericUpDown control = sender as NumericUpDown;
       decimal newValue = control.Value;

       // decimal newValue;
       // decimal.TryParse(control.Text, out newValue)

       if (newValue > control.Maximum || newValue < control.Minimum)
       {
            // MessageBox

        }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3021677/279982

Answer (score 3):

Nagging the user by slapping her with message boxes doesn't make for the greatest user interface.  But you can easily do it just by setting the min and max smaller/larger and checking the value in the ValueChanged event.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the value is changed without notification? I agree that message boxes can be annoying. But using ASP.NET like validation controls can be both more informative and less annoying.

Comment: No.  This question doesn't have anything to do with asp.net

Comment: "ASP.NET like" validation controls, I mean the method used there not the controls themselves. Implementation is possible and has been discussed in the link in my comment on the question.