# Is there any validation control available in .net win forms like asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

Is there any validation control available in .net win forms like asp.net web form?

Because it difficult to right condition for each control in my from also there are many repeated code in my form.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this, hope it helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950965.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a project that developed a free validator just like the web forms one. You can find it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/validationprovider.aspx).

Or you can use MaskedTextBox controls or event driven validations as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

ErrorProvider can work to some extent but still we need to write code for validation

Answer (score 0):

They are not validator controls but set of validation classes to build rules for validating objects.

The Enterprise Library has a Validation Application Block

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664378(v=PandP.50).aspx