# What's the proper way to do form validation in C#?

Tags: c#, validation, forms

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [WinForm UI Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)
>   [What is the best way to do validations in windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392555/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-validations-in-windows-forms)

I'm writing an application in C# that has a large number (>30) of forms (TextBox, RadioButton, and CheckBox) that span a wide variety of data types and I was wondering what the proper way to validate them all would be. Also, not all of the fields are required.

Comment: @Domenic based on the word "form" I would assume WinForm since WPF uses the term "window" but this also isn't the best question so who knows.

Comment: WinForm, WPF, Webform/ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC (which view engine)???